# adjust forms that are generated by django generic editing views

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models

I am trying to understand the process of generating generic form views in django. I have a generic view class with just

```
class BookUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Book
    fields = [  'name',
                'pages',
                'categorys'
                ]
```

which automatically generates a working html form from my model data. But now, I want to modify the field that is shown for `categorys`, is there any way to do this, or do I have to create a complete working `BookForm` class and custom `BookUpdate` class? Here its just 3 fields, but in my real case there are maybe 15 fields that I would need to code by myself, just because of a tiny change in the `category` field.

Cant I just overwrite the single field, using any class method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either specify `fields` or `form_class` in your generic class-based view. With `fields`, Django will use a modelform_factory to generate the form. There's not much you can customise then.

You should create a `BookForm` class so that you can customise the fields. In your `BookUpdate` view, you only need to remove `fields` and add `form_class = BookForm`. Here I'm customising the widget for `categorys` and overriding the form field for `pages`:

```
def BookUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Book
    form_class = BookForm

def BookForm(ModelForm):
    pages = MyCustomPagesField()

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'categorys': MyCustomWidget()}
```

Note that you don't have to specify all fields, you can use `"__all__"` to have all fields or you can set `exclude = [<list fields to exclude>]` to just exclude a couple.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to code the fields yourself. But there is a small amount of work to do, as there isn't a method to override.

What you need to do is define a custom form. Since that will be a ModelForm, it will use the same logic to automatically create its fields based on the model. You can then override the definition of one of them.

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm): 
     categorys = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(custom_attributes_here...)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ["name", "pages", "categorys"]
```

And now tell your view to use that form:

```
class BookUpdate(UpdateView):
    form_class = BookForm
```